# Ukraine (Cyrillic) characters not displaying in Jasper Report PDF

Tags: java, pdf, localization, jasper-reports

I am trying to display ukranian character in jasper report as a pdf file. but it is not diaplaying in pdf format.

when I export report to all other format like html, csv..ukranian char is displaying.

Comment: Do the fonts used for export have the characters necessary? I'm not sure what method Jasper Report uses, but the PDF file usually contains the font used for generating it - which means that font must support international characters.

Comment: http://maryniuk.blogspot.com/2010/09/custom-ttf-fonts-in-jasperreports.html this helped me

Answer (score 10):

Set some text field properties at iReport. Use font **DejaVu Sans**. Set pdf encoding to **Cp1251** and **isPdfEmbedded** to **true**.

Ex.: `<font fontName="DejaVu Sans" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfEncoding="Cp1251" isPdfEmbedded="true" />`

jasperreports fonts as maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: 3 years later... pdfEncoding is deprecated however jasperreports-fonts uses font-extensions if you like to use your own font, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041619/jasper-reports-pdf-doesnt-export-cyrillic-values/ for font-extension example.

Answer (score 8):

First, make sure you have the right encoding:

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

Then you should change the fonts to ones that support cyrillic. This is done via styles:

```
public void addPdfFontsToStyles(JRStyle[] styles) {
    if (styles != null) {
        for (JRStyle style : styles) {
            if (style.getName().equals("reportStyle")) {
                style.setPdfFontName("/com/yourcompany/fonts/times.ttf");
                style.setBlankWhenNull(true);
            }

            if (style.getName().equals("reportBoldStyle")) {
                style.setPdfFontName("/com/yourcompany/fonts/timesbd.ttf");
                style.setBlankWhenNull(true);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And invoke this method with `addPdfFontsToStyles(jasperReport.getStyles());`

Of course, the prerequisites are:

- your text is using one of the above style names
- you have the ttf files on the classpath

That should do it (I'm taking the code from a working cyrilic application)

Answer (score 2):

1. register font in JVM

   ```
   Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("pathToCyrillicFont"));
   GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(myFont);
   ```
2. add to Cyrillic field this:

   ```
   <textElement>
      <font
                     fontName="fontName"
                     pdfFontName="pathToCyrillicFont"
                     size="13"
                     isBold="false"
                     isItalic="false"
                     isUnderline="false"
                     isPdfEmbedded ="true"
                     pdfEncoding ="Cp1251"
                     isStrikeThrough="false"
      /> 
    </textElement>
   ```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Since jasper report v5, v6 the correct way to display characters in pdf is to use [font-extension](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension)

For more information see these question on stackoverflow:

[Jasper Reports PDF doesn't export cyrillic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041619/jasper-reports-pdf-doesnt-export-cyrillic-values/)

[How can I display "$£Ω€απ⅔" in Jasperserver PDF using iReport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940126/how-can-i-display-%C2%A3%E2%84%A6%E2%82%AC%CE%B1%CF%80%E2%85%94-in-jasperserver-pdf-using-ireport/)

Answer (score 0):

just stumbled over this, the solution for me was to add the font-resource on the server. Go to you report -> edit -> add Resources